# How to show caller in a Julia backtrace?

Tags: julia

Is there a way to get the file/name/line info for the caller of a Julia function?

I found [this way to get some stacktrace info](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/S485_5jG2Nw/discussion), and if the caller is another function (but not the main context) I get the file:line info:

```
module pd

   global g_bTraceOn = true

   export callerOfTraceIt

   function callerOfTraceIt()
     traceit( "hi" ) ;
   end

   function traceit( msg )
      global g_bTraceOn

      if ( g_bTraceOn )
         bt = backtrace() ;
         s = sprint(io->Base.show_backtrace(io, bt))

         println( "debug: $s: $msg" )
      end
   end
end

using pd

callerOfTraceIt( )
```

This shows:

```
$ julia bt.jl
debug:
 in traceit at C:\cygwin64\home\Peeter\julia\HarmonicBalance\bt.jl:15
 in callerOfTraceIt at C:\cygwin64\home\Peeter\julia\HarmonicBalance\bt.jl:8
 in include at boot.jl:245
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:128
 in process_options at client.jl:285
 in _start at client.jl:354: hi
```

I'd really like just the second frame (caller of traceit()), and would also like the function name if it's available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do `@show bt` inside `traceit`, you'll discover it's just a list of pointers, each corresponding to a single stack frame. Those stack frames that come from julia code (rather than C) are displayed by `show_backtrace`.

You can call `Profile.lookup(uint(bt[1]))` to extract file/function/line information from each element:

```
julia> Profile.lookup(uint(bt[1]))
LineInfo("rec_backtrace","/home/tim/src/julia-old/usr/bin/../lib/libjulia.so",-1,true,140293228378757)

julia> names(Profile.LineInfo)
5-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :func 
 :file 
 :line 
 :fromC
 :ip
```

You likely want to ignore all elements with `fromC == true`.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Here's how I'm using this:

https://github.com/peeterjoot/julia/blob/master/HarmonicBalance/pd.jl

... some of my first Julia code, but something like this is usually my first code in a new language.